# Почему я могу выполнить div для числа с точкой и Варианта в Делфи?

Tags: delphi

С удивлением обнаружил, что числа с точкой могут быть целочисленно поделены на Variant в Delphi. Простой пример:

```
var
  v: Variant;
begin
  v := 2.3;
  Tag := 5.1 div v; // 2
  Tag := 5.1 mod v; // 1
  Tag := 5.1 div 2; // [dcc32 Error] E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
  Tag := 5.1 mod 2; // [dcc32 Error] E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
end;
```

Похоже, что Delphi округляет левую и правую часть выражения перед выполнением div/mod операторов.

Я полагал, что вышенаписанный код вызовет ошибку при компилировании всех 4 строк, т.к. в моем понимании, операторы div/mod не применимы к числам с точкой от слова "совсем". Похоже что это не так.

Почему Delphi дает мне целочисленно поделить число с точкой на Variant, для чего нужна эта возможность?

Comment: например: при использовании variant, к этому типу приводятся все операнды, а так как этот тип может приводится к любому типу - то содержимое обеих переменных приводится к целому числу

Comment: Минуту, наверное сейчас ответ напишу :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В справке по [типу Variant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)#Variants_in_Expressions) есть следующее

> If an expression combines variants with statically-typed values, the statically-typed values are automatically converted to variants.

> Если в выражении используются переменные вариантных типов и статически-типизированные значения, статически-типизированные значения автоматически приводятся к вариантному типу.

---

В справке по [операторам](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operators)

> Except for ^, is, and in, all operators can take operands of type Variant;

> **Все** операторы, кроме **^**, **is** и **in** могут принимать операнды с типом Variant.

Из этого следует, что в выражениях

```
Tag := 5.1 div v; // 2
Tag := 5.1 mod v; // 1
```

число *5.1* было приведено к типу Variant

---

При использовании типа Variant в операциях, если исходное значение не подходит для операции оно конвертируется в подходящее по определенным правилам. Правила указаны в специальной таблице.